Synthcity DECAF shape error in generative Artificial Intelligence
I'm trying to generate new data utilizing the DECAF generator, but I get an error I cannot solve.
I am using the exact same code as mentioned in the docs of the main repo (Link Synthcity Docs):
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from synthcity.plugins import Plugins

X, y = load_iris(as_frame = True, return_X_y = True)
X["target"] = y

plugin = Plugins().get("decaf", n_iter = 100)
plugin.fit(X)

plugin.generate(50)

I keep on getting
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (150, 1), indices imply (150, 3)

no matter what I'm doing. I'm kind of surprised that the error occurs at all, since it is actually a case study of the author.
Is anybody able to explain or more important solve this error?
